# Right angle gearbox, proper name or design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms, power-transmission

I'm looking for right angle gearbox, but everything is horrible expensive or in parts like two bevel gears from aliexpress.
Where I can find or how to name transmission like this in the picture but in box case (if possible with mounting holes)?

I need right angle transmission 1:1, no matter what type of gear or something else. Looking for compact size, outer size of one arm, max 40mmx40mm. Maybe I don't know proper name to find it.

Also if I don't find good out of the box solution, how to proper design that type of transmission? I know I need bearings on shaft and screw, but how to avoid skipping on teeth?

[image]

Comment: Just like to point out that the bevel gears as shown aren’t meant to mesh at 90 degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminology is correct, but also sometimes called bevel gearboxes. A cheap off the shelf unit is a few hundred dollars. If that is too expensive you probably won't save any money designing and fabricating the gears and housing yourself. A u-joint is a cheaper alternative.

But if you are intent on making your own, Boston Gear has good catalogue parts and resources. KHK gear also has good technical resources online.

Comment: thanks, I think that I'll use dobule cardan joint. I'm a bit affraid of 90 degree transmission efficiency, won't it be to much resistance on joints? I need to lift about 200N per one joint.

Comment: Depends on the efficiency of the joint and how much torque (N*m) it's rated for.

Answer (score 3):

these things are sold cheaply (less than $20) for bending the output of an electric drill through 90 degrees, so you can drill holes in cramped places. they can handle  from 1/4 to 1/3 horsepower typically. hardware stores sell them. they are called *right angle drill drive attachments*.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found on my local store 105 degree attachment, I'm courius if there are gears that I can set for 90 degrees after displacement, maybe you have some knowledge about that?

Comment: oh yeah, the 90 degree ones are the most common.

Comment: 90deg ones are actually not that common - they're often a bit higher than 90deg to account for the thickness of the drill body when getting into tight spaces per their intended use. I needed 90deg for a similar project to you (using it as a gearbox), and used this one - https://www.axminstertools.com/axminster-right-angle-drive-attachment-506682

Comment: @JonathanRSwift did you disassembled that adapter or made some mounting? If you disassembled it what's inside?

Comment: I 3D Printed a housing to clamp it in